# No out of bound in Matlab

Tags: matlab, outofrangeexception

I notice the following in Matlab.

```
>> a = [1, 3];
>> a(3, 4) = 1
a =

 1     2     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
>> a(5, 4)
??? Attempted to access a(5,4); index out of bounds because size(a)=[3,4].
```

Isn't `a` of size 1 by 2 initially? Why wouldn't it complain out of bound when I write to `a(3, 4)` but only when I read `a(5, 4)`?

Answer (score 8):

When you write to a previously non-existing element in an array, the array is augmented to the new size, and padded with zeros in case of a numeric array, or empty elements with e.g. cells or structs. This is done for your convenience, since augmenting the array by yourself requires a lot of typing. Note that for actual code, you may often want to avoid changing array size like this, since it may decrease readability, and it can noticeably affect performance if you grow an array like this inside a loop with many iterations. Thus, it is generally better to pre-assign your arrays to the correct size (which has the added benefit of giving you control over the padding value).

When you want to read a non-existing element, there is nothing that can be read. Conceivably, Matlab could return 0 or `NaN`, but reading outside the bounds is much less likely to happen on purpose than writing, so Matlab throws an error.